# Mostrar informação de campo date - php symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco com dados do tipo date, as datas no banco estão nesse formato:

```
2009-09-10.
```

Estou tentando trazer elas via json do symfony desse jeito:

```
linha 7: date("d/m/Y", strtotime($tbdeliberacoes->getData()))
```

no meu arquivo de personalização do campo está assim:

```
 $this->widgetSchema['data'] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array('label' => 'Data'));
```

mas é esse erro que não deixa os dados aparecerem na tela:

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in line 7
```

ja pesquisei e não achei nada que me ajudasse.

Answer (score 2):

Vou te mostrar uma função que uso aqui que faz essa conversão de formato inglês para português de datas

```
Class datas {
public function ajusta_data($char1,$char2,$dt) {

    if ($char1 == "-") {
        if ($dt < "1900-01-01 00:00:00" OR $dt > "2100-12-31 23:59:59") {
            $ret = "";
            return $ret;
        }
        $dia = 2;
    } else {
        $dia = 0;
    }

    $temp = explode($char1,substr($dt,0,10));
    if ($temp[1] == '02' AND $temp[$dia] > 28) {$temp[$dia] = 28;}
    if (($temp[1] == '04' OR $temp[1] == '06' OR $temp[1] == '09' OR $temp[1] == '11') AND $temp[$dia] > 30) {$temp[$dia] = 30;}
    if ($temp[0] != "0000" AND $temp[0] != "") $dt  = $temp[2].$char2.$temp[1].$char2.$temp[0].substr($dt,10,10);

    if ($char2 == "-") {
        if ($dt < "1900-01-01 00:00:00" OR $dt > "2100-12-31 23:59:59") {
            $ret = "";
            return $ret;
        }
    }

    return $dt;
  }
}
```

Aí vou usar, uso o include na página que vou precisar

```
$n_dt   =   new datas();
```

Depois pego a data que quero e geralmente coloco numa variável pra não precisar usar a função toda santa vez

```
    $dt_nascimento = $n_dt->ajusta_data('/','-',$_POST['dt_nascimento']);
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre pois o conteúdo de `$tbdeliberacoes->getData()` é um objeto do tipo `\DateTime`, e não um inteiro (no caso, a data em formato UNIX). Basta usar o método `format` para exibir a data no formato que você quer.

Ou seja, ao invés de fazer isso:

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($tbdeliberacoes->getData()));
```

... faça isso:

```
$tbdeliberacoes->getData()->format('d/m/Y');
```